# Value of integral involving $\tan x$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$ \int_{0} ^ {\pi/4} \frac {\tan^2x}{1+x ^2} dx$$

I have tried using $x=\tan \theta$.
But in my opinion i am finding that this might not be closed  form.
Please help.

Comment: no . in denom it becomes problematic

Comment: what are you saying ? plz check once. i think you are getting confused

Comment: @deepak .it will not solve.

Comment: Sorry but derivative of $\tan(x)$ is not $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: @DougM Are you confusing tangent and arctangent?

Comment: Definite duplicate.